# pthreads_create causing segment faults for no apparent reason

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

i have been writing some function that needs to multile threaded in C , pthreads seemed like a no brainer.But now that i have written it out it is giving my segment faults all the time , with a bunch of printf() statements and commenting out part of codes i figured out that pthread_create is causing these , any help would be appreciated! As far as i can see me passing in the parameters to pthread_create seems perfectly fine.

code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
typedef unsigned long long ll;
struct opscount{
    ll faddpthread;
    ll fsubpthread;
    ll fmulpthrea;
    ll fdivpthread;
};
int main(){
    int total_thread,time;
    printf("Enter total number of threads : ");
    scanf("%i",&total_thread);
    printf("Time to run the test : ");
    scanf("%i",&time);
    struct opscount opcount[total_thread];
    pthread_t thread[total_thread];
    //---------------------start of fadd test----------------------------------
    for(int i=0;i<total_thread;i++)
    {
        opcount[i].faddpthread=0;
        pthread_create(&thread[i],NULL,faddtf,opcount+i);
    }
    int optime=time/4;
    sleep(optime);
    for(int i=0;i<total_thread;i++)
    {
        pthread_cancel(thread[i]);// kills the threads
    }
}
```

the thread function being :

```
void *faddtf(void *oppthread)
{
    double c=0.75665;
    while(true)
    {
        c+=v1+v2+v3+v4+v5;
        ((struct opscount *)oppthread)->faddpthread+=5;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok after a little bit of googling i came across this : https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/pthread_create-immediate-seg-fault-4175651523/
i figured that passing in a stuct as parameter to pthread_create is causing toubles , i swapped that out with a array and it surely fixed the error.

Comment: Re, "...struct as parameter...array..." That doesn't make sense. The only thing you can pass to the new thread is a _pointer._ It should not matter what the pointer points to so long as (a) the thing that it points to continues to exist for the lifetime of the thread, and (b) both the caller of `pthread_create(..., my_pointer)` and the code that runs in the thread both agree on the size and the type of that thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has two bugs.

One is that the thread that runs `main` can terminate, destroying the stack on which `opcount` exists. This can happen before the threads have actually had a chance to terminate. You don't wait for them to terminate. (And they won't terminate because of the second bug.)

The second bug is that the threads you try to cancel don't have any way to be cancelled. They don't check if they've been cancelled. They don't enable async cancellation.

What's likely happening is your code crashes when the threads access objects on the first thread's stack after the first thread has terminated and succeeds if, by luck, the process terminates before that happens because returning from `main` terminates the process.

Comment: so if I make the main thread wait for the threaded functions , both my bugs get fixed ? I am guessing u are talking about pthread_join here.

Comment: Well the call to `pthread_join` will never return since your threads never terminate. They don't support cancellation, so calling `pthread_cancel` on them doesn't do anything. They have no cancellation points and don't support asynchronous cancellation, so there is no way to cancel them.

Comment: Okay , so i need another function in between that has a return statement and returns after the sleep , also do i need pthear_cancel even when using pthread_join with return functions?

Comment: It's hard to answer without understanding what you're actually trying to do. Why are you canceling threads? Why not just code the thread to only do work that you want them to do so you don't have to "reach in from the outside" to cancel them?